Static linking in clang++ doesn't staticly link
I am new to c++ and created first program, it compiles and works on my machine but when i sent it to a friend they got 2 errors, basically:
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll not found
libwinpthread-1.dll not found
this is my compile command
  "command": "clang++",
  "args": [
    "-static-libgcc",
    "-static-libstdc++",
    "-static",
    "-LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib",
    "-g",
    "${workspaceFolder}\Oneko.cpp",
    "${workspaceFolder}\Oneko_res.o",
    "-o",
    "${workspaceFolder}\Oneko.exe",
    "-lgdiplus",
    "-lole32",
    "-mwindows"
  ]

i tried compiling it statically but nothing works, help :<

Don't specify -LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib, it should get added automatically (and if not, it's a sign of a misconfiguration). Also you don't need -static-..., the -static alone implies both.

Are you sure you're actually using your tasks.json? Where EXACTLY do you click to run the build? What if you build manually in the terminal?

I use ctrl + shift + B, i see in terminal that it uses this command

When i manually compile with thic command it compiles with no issue, but it still has same error

This should work. Are you sure you're sending the .exe you're compiling, and not some other one? Try compiling twice, with and without -static (don't add -static-... to both) and compare the file sizes.

Does your friend have MinGW64 installed?  Does your friend's C:\msys64\mingw64\lib have both libgcc_s_seh-1.dll and libwinpthread-1.dll?  Does your friend have C:\msys64\mingw64\lib in their path?

size with static: 854KB, without: 296KB

My friend does't have mingw64, that's the point, I want it to be download and run

Whole code for this program is here @HolyBlackCat
